# Parallelization in MissForest

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, na

I have a dataframe `data3` with 54 factor and numerical variables and 285331 records. I am about to fill NAs with MissForest package and am trying to parallelize in order to reduce the processing time however if I use the following code:

```
library(missForest)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
data4 <- missForest(data3, maxiter = 10, ntree = 100, mtry = 100, variablewise = T, parallelize = "forests")
data4$OOBerror
apply(data3,2,var,na.rm=TRUE) 
apply(is.na(data4$ximp),2,sum) 
data3 <- data4$ximp
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in missForest(data3, maxiter = 10, ntree = 100, mtry = 100, variablewise = T, : You must register a 'foreach' parallel backend to run 'missForest' in parallel. Set 'parallelize' to 'no' to compute serially.
```

What is there missing in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need the package "doParallel" (see below)

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 16)
```